# How do you paste filtered values only in the cells that were affected by such filter using vba?

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste

I'm currently working on a Macro that its currently filtering a table based on a value and then it copies the data under a column after the filters have been applied (got that to work). However, I can't figure out how to paste those values in the same table overwriting the data under the visible cells within a different column. Values highlighted in red (picture) are being copied, now I need to paste them over only in the cells highlighted yellow. Thank you!

```
Public Sub DxcDateUpdate()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Mwb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set Mwb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = Mwb.Worksheets("Commission")
Set ws2 = Mwb.Worksheets("test")
        
        
lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
ws.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=31, Criteria1:="DXC/TPV.com Enrollment"
ws.Range("AG2:AG" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=ws.Range '''here is where idk what to do?'''
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot paste a discontinuous range as discontinuous. You should iterate between each range cell and copy it using offset, or building the range to Paste using `c.row`. Please, try the next adapted code:

```
Sub DxcDateUpdate()
Dim Mwb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, rngVis As Range, c As Range, LR As Long

Set Mwb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = Mwb.Worksheets("Commission")
Set ws2 = Mwb.Worksheets("test")
        
        
LR = ws.cells(ws.rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
ws.Range("A1").AutoFilter field:=31, Criteria1:="DXC/TPV.com Enrollment"
Set rngVis = ws.Range("AG2:AG" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) 
 For Each c In rngVis.cells
    c.Offset(0, -28).value = c.value
 Next
End Sub
```

In order to make the code faster, of course, you should use some optimization lines (ScreenUpdating = False, EnableEvents = False, Calculation = xlCalculationManual, followed after by `True`, `True`, `xlCalculationAutomatic`).

Comment: Kind of more readable (maintainable) could be `c.EntireRow.Columns("E").Value = c.Value`. To speed it up, you should consider looping through the areas: `For Each c In rngVis.Areas`.

Comment: `Dim LR As Long` is missing. Replace `End If` with `Next c`. Consider removing any filters before and after: `ws.AutoFilterMode = False`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 thank you for that second option! I'll definitely add it to the notes since its more understandable word-wise.

FaneDuru - Just to make sure, instead of the "End If", I changed it to a "Next c" because it was giving me an error. Its doing what its supposed to be doing now, but is what I did correct?

Comment: @VBasic2008: Yes, your comments are pertinent, thanks! I only tried rapidly adapting his code, in order to do what (I understood) he needs. I did it before leaving the office, not tested, of course. Corrected now.

Comment: @Socramvm: Of course, it should be `Next` (with or without `c`...). I made the code before leaving the office and I wrote `End If` by mistake. Of course, I did not test the code. I only wanted to show you a way to copy a discontinuous range in another discontinuous one...

Comment: @VBasic2008: I do not think that iterating before between the areas and only then between cells, the code will be faster. I think it will be slower. Practically the iteration between cells is kept and we would only introduce an extra iteration between areas. It can be a little faster for cases of areas having more then 1 row, ** only by copying the area Value (like an array) in the necessary range, resizing its first cell**, I think...

Comment: I used your variable names in the 'areas part' of my first comment to kind of let you know that iterating through the areas wouldn't need iterating through their cells i.e. just replace `.Cells` with `.Areas`.

Comment: @VBasic2008: I was confused by `For Each c In rngVis.Areas` and that `c` I used made me thinking to a Range, but you are right.

Answer (score 2):

### Copy 'Filtered' Values Using Arrays

- The following will loop through the criteria column to find the criteria (string). When found, in the same row, the value from the source column will be copied to the destination column.
- The columns' values are written to arrays to speed up the process (the loop).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub DxcDateUpdate()
    
    Const wsName As String = "Commission"
    Const fRow As Long = 2
    Const cCol As String = "AE" ' Criteria
    Const sCol As String = "AG" ' Source
    Const dCol As String = "E"  ' Destination
    Const Criteria As String = "DXC/TPV.com Enrollment"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim lRow As Long: lRow = rg.Rows.Count
    
    Dim cData As Variant: cData = rg.Columns(cCol).Value
    Dim sData As Variant: sData = rg.Columns(sCol).Value
    
    With rg.Columns(dCol)
        Dim dData As Variant: dData = .Value
        Dim r As Long
        For r = fRow To lRow
            If cData(r, 1) = Criteria Then
                dData(r, 1) = sData(r, 1)
            End If
        Next r
        .Value = dData
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice, voted up! I am a kind of array oriented guy, usually consider challenging and answer questions involving arrays in a potential answer... If I would have such a need, I would certainly choose the arrays variant, instead of filtering. I didn't even look at the filter criteria, in order to make me think at it. Good for you!